# Пользователи не добавляются в базу данных в Django

Tags: python, django

Я пытаюсь создать расширенную модель пользователя, но когда я регистрирую новый аккаунт, он не отображается в панели администратора, а самой таблицы пользователей там нету. Как это исправить? Вот структура проекта:

```
│   db.sqlite3
│   manage.py
│
├───ithogwarts
│   │   asgi.py
│   │   settings.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   wsgi.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│
├───main
│   │   admin.py
│   │   apps.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   tests.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───migrations
│   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   │
│   ├───static
│   │   └───main
│   │       ├───css
│   │       │       footer.css
│   │       │       header.css
│   │       │       index.css
│   │       │
│   │       ├───img
│   │       │
│   │       └───js
│   │               script.js
│   │
│   ├───templates
│   │   └───main
│   │           index.html
│   │           layout.html
│   │           level_magic.html
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│
├───templates
│   └───registration
└───users
    │   admin.py
    │   apps.py
    │   forms.py
    │   models.py
    │   tests.py
    │   urls.py
    │   utils.py
    │   views.py
    │   __init__.py
    │
    ├───migrations
    │   │   0001_initial.py
    │   │   __init__.py
    │   │
    │   └───__pycache__
    │
    ├───static
    │   └───users
    │       └───css
    │               login.css
    │               register.css
    │
    ├───templates
    │   └───users
    │           login.html
    │           register.html
    │
    └───__pycache__
```

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    level = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("level"), null=True)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm

from .models import CustomUser


class RegisterUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Имя", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'register__form-title form-control',
                                                                          'placeholder': 'введите ваше имя'}))
    email = forms.CharField(label="Почта", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'register__form-title form-control',
                                                                          'placeholder': 'введите вашу почту'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(label="Пароль", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'register__form-title form-control',
                                                                          'placeholder': 'введите пароль'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label="Подтверждение пароля", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'register__form-title form-control',
                                                                          'placeholder': 'подтвердите ваш пароль'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name in ['username', 'password1', 'password2']:
            self.fields[field_name].help_text = None

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'password1': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}),
            'password2': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'})
        }
```

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView

from .forms import RegisterUserForm, LoginUserForm


def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')


class RegisterUser(CreateView):
    form_class = RegisterUserForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'users/register.html'
```

ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно в  settings.py указать модель которая будет использоваться для аутентификации

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
```